# How to get progress from Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, progress, fetch-api

I'm using  `$.ajax`,i can do that:

```
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
//Upload progress
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
    //Do something with upload progress
    console.log(percentComplete);
  }
}, false);
```

But,when i use fetch api,what should i do?

```
var fData = new FormData();
fData.append("userfile",document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
fetch("/", {method:"POST",body:fData}).then(function(res){});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of right now, you can't. It's not part of the spec yet. There was an [issue](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/21) for it on the spec's repo but it's closed. There's also some discussion on this [issue](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/89) about it.

Long story short, you are probably better off just sticking with `xhr` for now unless you want to try some of the polyfills/workarounds in the second issue Iinked.

It's just not supported, and that is also the reason `fetch` requests don't show up in the network tab in the devtools untill they've completed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  ^-^!

Comment: The last statement is not true anymore.

Comment: @maracuja-juice I'll happily approve an edit to this answer if you want to update it with the current situation.